# SFTP creating new directory

Tags: sftp, scheduling

I am doing SFTP to transfer files .
But during the process , if the path doesn't exists ,  the sftp is creating a directory bydefault ? Can anyone please explain this to me

Comment: it depends on sftp client.

Comment: It 's unclear what you are asking. Do you _want_ to create a directory? Where? Locally or on the server?

Comment: No i want , if the destination path doesn' exist , it should give me an error

Comment: @piemesson That's the default in the `sftp` installed with OpenSSH.

Comment: Hi , thanks @kusalananda  can you please provide me the link or doc which says that it is a default behaviour ?

Comment: It's hardly documented. If it were on the contrary, it might have been documented. But you cannot expect a software to document that it **does not do** something.

Comment: I mean is it a bug , or a deliberate attempt , because in ftp if there is no destination it gives error instead of making a new directory . Have you also faced such problem ?

Comment: What command do you use in `sftp`? I believe the behavior is different with and without the `-r` switch (and there's no such switch in `ftp`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the OpenSSH `sftp` client, if the local path of the `get` command contains a directory that does not exist, you will get an error.

This is the code (see the `do_download()` function in [`sftp-client.c`](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/sftp-client.c?rev=1.126&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)):

```
local_fd = open(local_path,
    O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | (resume_flag ? 0 : O_TRUNC), mode | S_IWUSR);
if (local_fd == -1) {
    error("Couldn't open local file \"%s\" for writing: %s",
        local_path, strerror(errno));
    goto fail;
}
```

No attempt is made to create the directory if it doesn't exist.

Testing this:

```
sftp> lls hello
ls: hello: No such file or directory
Shell exited with status 1
sftp> get Documents/answers.txt hello/world
Fetching /home/kk/Documents/answers.txt to hello/world
Couldn't open local file "hello/world" for writing: No such file or directory
sftp> lls hello
ls: hello: No such file or directory
Shell exited with status 1
sftp>
```

If `sftp` is started with `-r` or if the `get` command is used with the same flag, then the destination directory *will* be created.  This is from `download_dir_internal()` in `sftp-client.c` which is where we end up from `process_get()` in `sftp.c` if the `-r` flag is used:

```
if (mkdir(dst, mode) == -1 && errno != EEXIST) {
    error("mkdir %s: %s", dst, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}
```

This seems logical to me. If you want to recursively download files, you shouldn't need to manually create the directory structure prior to getting the files.

Comment: But with `get -r`, the target directory is created, if it does not exist.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes. I will update the answer.

Comment: Actually I do not find it logical. It'd say it is rather a side effect of the implementation of the `download_dir_internal`. +1 anyway

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No, imagine `cp -r` or `rsync -r` requiring you to first do a bunch of `mkdir` calls before you could actually do the copying... You would have to use something like a `find /source -type d ...` approach to map the directory structure between the source and the target first, and it would easily become quite messy over a network.